# How does one backup to iCloud? “Backup Now” greyed out

Tags: iphone, ios

Googled "how to force iphone backup to icloud greyed out" but none of the top answer options exist on my iPhone 6. Logged in with Apple ID, not connected to wi-fi.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Ask Different. Have you tried when the iPhone is connected to Wi-Fi? According to Apple (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203977#icloud), you must connect your device to a Wi-Fi network.

Comment: Have you recently restored the device from a backup? Which version of iOS are you running?